# comparing 2 char arrays for % difference

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 text boxes (winforms app) on a button press I have the following code:

```
        string new_text = txtnew.Text;
        string old_text = txtold.Text;

        char[] arr_new = new_text.ToCharArray();
        char[] arr_old = old_text.ToCharArray();
        double found  = 0.0;
        double not_found = 0.0;
        foreach (char c_old in arr_old)
        {
            foreach (char c_new in arr_new)
            {
                if (c_new == c_old)
                {
                    found++;
                }else{
                    not_found++;
                }
            }
        }
        double percentage //need help here..
        MessageBox.Show(percentage.ToString());
```

What I've been trying to do is compare each array to see if a character from 1 array exists in the other array and then it's supposed to output the difference as percentage. So if txtNew = "hello worl" and txtold="hello world" then the difference would be like 0.1% ? anyway the more it gets modified the bigger the difference is until it's at a safe state of 60% different.

Comment: How did you get .1% difference in your example. It would more like 10% difference. This only works if the strings are exactly the same length otherwise. **If 9/10 characters match thats 90%.** Why don't you just divide the number of characters that matched to the length of the string. You find the difference by subtracting the match percentage ( decmial value ) from 1.

Comment: It's not clear what you consider to be the difference is the difference between dog and god 0? They have all the same chars.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - Based on his example it would be 2/3 character matched so 33% difference and 77% match.

Comment: @Ramhound sounds about right :p

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the percentage by dividing the `not_found` by the total, like this:

```
double percentage = (100.0 * not_found) / (found + not_found);
```

A more precise way to do it would be to calculate the [*Edit Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the strings, and then express that distance in terms of the percentage of the length of the original string (i.e. using the edit distance instead of `not_found`).

Comment: +1 Levenshtein FTW. Here's a C# implementation: http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

Answer (score 0):

If you increase `not_found` in the inner loop it's going to up to `old_text.Length*new_text.Length`. This will generate huge `not_found` numbers giving you much smaller percentages than I think you are after.

Also no point in doing the char array stuff, and the inner can be replaced by an `IndexOf` call:

```
    string new_text = txtnew.Text;
    string old_text = txtold.Text;

    var found = 0;
    foreach (var c_old in old_text)
    {
        if (new_text.IndexOf(c_old) != -1)
        {
          found++;
        }
    }
    //percentage of characters in the old text that also appear in the new text
    double percentage = (100d * found) / old_text.Length;    
    MessageBox.Show(percentage.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Wikipedia page:
[Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)

There is a C# function provided on that page which I think does exactly what you're looking for.

Edit: Just realized someone else already referred to this same algorithm, sorry for the duplicate.